# How can i convert hex string to readable format?

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have an image.I have converted this image to NSData and then the NSData to hexadecimal string using byte array.I have then decoded this hexadecimal string to  nsnstring using NSUTF8String encoding but it gives me weird string in non readable format .The string displayed is :

```
 IHDR¿”uÓ®iDOTÍ(ÍÈ5·YÛ˙π@IDATxLºsG∂∂y¿∆∆Óu#ÕÃï•$zêAaÇûAÔ)íùDë“H#i43Ú&lt;⁄{o´Ω∑ﬁìîÓ∑˚7ˆ)Ù˝&quot;6‚DEvuuuUV÷…&lt;Oæ&apos;ˇE˜€®ˆÂàÊ≈®Ó∑q≈RJ≥ñQ,ƒßº˝£ÆG    ]∆¨úqèYGL√£Ê    °ì4cLËz¬JÏIP&quot;…Ë{&quot;Úø[~ïèöÙ≥ÆG˛°æò˚ﬁ˘ÏGw/&lt;ˆÀû‰ø:qÙ˚äà^P˜⁄eÇ‹ö≤©&lt;Jâ}X‘ËjÖO™ÙH¥&gt;π¡ßx¨¯∂_ˇÀ∞˘â#Æ3áîa»‡óÈ}RùG∆∑∂à3tzØ⁄µö¸zµS1†Î5zµÆòÕ6ÈïŒ£‚åÇﬁØußùŒîU„UòÉzå≤ﬂ‡”àﬂ
*[»ËM8≠~É…£’ªTVø…±[=ªœ§∂…ÿiˆÍ\´=h2∏’ˆ∞YH8ÿ™Ï2µCnô¯»z‹    á“.”πïúÕË”ºZk»b    ö’Ç¶OﬂØÒ®M!£%h¥G,ÊÄI&apos;h]Qó/Â3∏µFAßu®ƒÙõLΩ3lsÑ¨*´\Ô“8£V_⁄ÌI:C£æ»D–ìrqùæ§ã=‚ùF,ò-l6‘ChÃ/$ùÏ·[w‹nÚlAW%ÓIπbSaÆä∫Ú$‹‚W≥=h·ø|I!:Ú&amp;‹Aœˇ∫#Ç;Ê±ÜlÊêÕïˆ⁄≤^}⁄•t≥AÀZRµyî±&gt;uÃ¯{&apos;=Cs¡°Ÿ¿\px&gt;‘?ÌöHó¬è«ù?§Lè∆O&apos;›}≥æ˛9Ôåóùøåÿ~µ?õpÙL:èZçX˛◊| ü“ˇî2&lt;∑œz{∆Ï√SÇl÷«vp¬’7·Ïüt)ÁÚün9™Y˜éÿz≤VÈîgh‹eXäÀ&apos;}í1A6ÌWŒÖÜg¸O≥ˆÔ&quot;⁄gcˆ˛)˜–¨wp∆√∂w¬˘K ¯8kQØƒ±°iüd6†\ä ¬ä≈àl&gt;‘3Í‰∑œFz«\òt.(nB√sÓHı&lt;1¥z6%
```

I want to get the text which was there on the image.Is there any way that i can convert  the hex string to unicode chars so that i can later on parse it to get the data i want?

Comment: Hmm.. I think you have some basic misunderstanding about image data formats.. To put it mildly..

Comment: A hexadecimal string looks like "DEADBEAF" or "8BADF00D" (letters 0-9, A-F only). It is the same in ASCII or UTF8/Unicode .. now, even if the original data was converted to a byte[] of only "hex" values [0,16) that *still* wouldn't produce that output when decoded as UTF-8 .. in any case, **post the code**.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're doing, but it sounds like you're trying to convert text in the image itself to a string - something you can't do this way.

Also the string you pasted are for the most part unicode chars.